# MongoDB Arrays in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb

Just started using MongoDB. I'm curious about the non-traditional (compared to sql db's) data type: array. Seems like a very powerful feature, but haven't seen too many people use it. I'd like to know what are some examples of good uses for Mongo's Arrays? In particular, with Rails.

Perhaps my question is too subjective, but I would still say worthy of answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

We use arrays in documents a lot. You can even index them, and use operators like `$push`, `$pull`, etc. These operators make arrays a natural choice for a lot of use cases that needed to be handled via 1:n or n:m relationships in the SQL world. You can read up more on array operators [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating).